Is the spherical outgoing wave solution to the Schrodinger equation not a member of $L^2$?
I was reading a discussion about the Mott problem, where the authors discuss the outgoing spherical wave solutions to the Helmholtz equations $\nabla^2 f = - k^2 f$. This equation can also be identified with the time-independent Schrodinger equation for a particle subjected to spherically symmetric potential. The solution is given as
$$f = \frac{e^{i {\bf k.R}}}{R}$$
where ${\bf R} = (x,y,z)$.
The authors further discuss that this solution is not in $L^2$, and the probability interpretation fails for $|f|^2$, which you can find in the attached figure.

Can someone explain why the outgoing spherical wave solution to the Helmholtz equation is not in $L^2$ or the probability interpretation fails, as the authors discuss?

@VaibhavK, Could you elaborate a bit? What exactly is not clear?

Oops, my bad, I thought the image was a part of your question and thought you wanted to add some more after the "we write.." sentence.

Integrating in spherical coordinates, we have
$$
\|f\|_2 = \int |f|^2d^3\mathbf{R} = \int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{R^2}\right)\left(R^2dR\,d^2\Omega\right) = 4\pi\int_0^\infty dR = \infty.
$$
So $f$ is not in $L_2$. Similarly, since $|f|^2$ cannot be scaled so that it integrates to $1$, there's no way to interpret it as a proper probability distribution.

Thanks. It absolutely makes sense why $f$ is not in $L^2$. In my mind, I was always thinking that this integral will converge.  Still, we can define some sort of relative probability using f, right? Gamov has used this wavefunction to describe the tunneling of $\alpha$ particles. Without some sort of probability description, using $f$ as a wavefunction would not make sense. I will look into this.

The simplest form of the  problem of this kind is the energy eigenstate for free particles wich is a plane wave and diverges if you take the integral of the square from -infinity to +infinitiy. One uses box normalization for practical purposes. The corresponding spectrum in momentum space is delta function. However the thruth is that there are neither delta functions(infinitely narrow functions with finite integral)  nor infinitely extended waves in nature but wave packets of finite size however long it may be.
